# "Bad Credentials" - Unable to sign in to Magento Marketplace via admin UI - upgrade to 2.0.3 fails

Tags: magento2, magento-connect

On the "Web Setup Wizard" there are two places to sign in:

1) Component Manager - via "Sign In" link.
2) System Config - via form.

Both forms ask for Public & Private Access Keys which I have generated as per the instructions here:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/comp-mgr/prereq/prereq_auth-token.html

When I click "Sign In" button (on Component Manager page) or "Save Config" button (on System Config page) i get a message "Bad Credentials"

I have tried:

a) regenerating keys.

b) generating new keys.

c) generating a new magentocommerce.com account and generating new keys.

I have verified that I am copy/pasting the keys correctly, with no leading/trailing spaces, etc.

At the moment there is a critical update which I cannot update to because the System Upgrade requires a valid login for it to work.

Currently the system upgrade fails to download the file:

https://repo.magento.com/archives/magento/framework/magento-framework-100.0.5.0.zip

This upgrade failure requires a filesystem restore to fix and the installation is broken until the **`vendor/magento/framework`** directory is restored.

Suggestions on how to fix the login problem please?

Comment: I am also getting same erro message.

Comment: Same here with the error message. Glad I'm not alone!

Comment: Same problem here :)

Comment: I believe that access to `repo.magento.com` is restricted for everyone right now while we issue a 2.0.4 patch. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I was running: `bin/magento sampledata:deploy` and getting crazy with the `Invalid credentials` for `repo.magento.com`. Glad I'm not alone either!

Comment: The Magento "Copy Key" adds a space at the beginning of the keys, so copy the two keys manually and carefully exclude any whitespace in front and end.